Writing a small paraquet dataframe into google cloud storage using spark 3.5.0 taking too long
We are using Spark on-premise to simply read a parquet file from GCS(Google Cloud storage) into the DataFrame and write the DataFrame into another folder in parquet format in GCS, using below code:
DFS_BLOCKSIZE = 512 * 1024 * 1024


spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("test_app_parquet_load") \
 .config("spark.master", "spark://spark-master-svc:7077") \
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", '1g') \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", '1g') \
     .config("spark.executor.cores",4) \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 16) \
       .config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", DFS_BLOCKSIZE) \

 .getOrCreate()


folder="gs://input_folder/input1/key=20240610"

print(f"reading parquet from {folder}")

start_time1 = time.time()

data_df = spark.read.parquet(folder)

end_time1 = time.time()

print(f"Time duration for reading parquet t1: {end_time1 - start_time1}")
 

start_time2 = time.time()

data_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("gs://output_folder/output/key=20240610")

end_time2 = time.time()

print(f"Time duration for writing parquet t3: {end_time2 - start_time2}")

spark.stop()


However, we observed a drastic time difference between Spark 2.4.5 and 3.5.0 in the writing process.
In Spark 2.4.5, the above code takes about 10 seconds for Parquet to read and 20 seconds for write, while in Spark 3.5.0 read takes almost similar time but write takes nearly 3 minutes. The size of the file is just 3 MB. Further, we have noticed that if we read a CSV file instead of parquet into DataFrame and write to another folder in parquet format, Spark 3.5.0 takes relatively less time to write, about 30-40 seconds.
So, it looks like only reading a parquet file and writing to another parquet file is taking too long in the case of Spark 3.5.0.
Can anyone suggest if there is any configuration related to Parquet that can be applied in Spark 3.5.0 to improve the write time? We have tried disabling the adaptive query execution mode also, but still, it takes about 3 mins to write.

Use SparkUI to profile your job and see where the time is being spent. Look for tasks that take a long time to complete and see if there are any skewed tasks. Also, if the file is small you can reduce the number of partitions using coalesce. You can try reducing the shuffle partition number as well (16 to 8 or something that works for this usecase).

@VikasSharma we already had checked in UI and see  "Executor compute time" taking the most time (3 mins), at DataframeWriter. scala(line 792), most time consuming stage seems to be InMemoryTableScan and WriteFiles. Also, the dataframe has just a single partition. Besides, why with same configuration the write works fast with spark version 2.4.5 but not with version 3.5.0.

Just to add some more details, we are seeing that there is no slowness even with Spark 3.1.2. So, it seems that the issue with spark job taking too long to write a parquet based dataframe into another parquet file (in gcs or local filesystem both) is specific to spark 3.5.0. Looks to be either a potential bug in Spark 3.5.0 or some parquet related configuration that is not clearly documented. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

On further analysis, I found out that the task WholeStageCodeGen(1) --> ColumnarToRow is the one which is taking the most time (almost 3 mins for a simple 3 mb file). Input batch size of this stage is 10,and output record count is 30,000.     The same CoumnarToRow task in spark 3.1.2 finishes in 10 secs.
Further, with spark 3.5.0 if I cache the dataframe and materialise it using df.count() and then write the df into parquet file, then the ColumnarToRow gets called twice, first takes 10 secs and second one 3 mins.
